# Checking whether array elements are symmetric

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Let's say I have an array in this format:

```
[8888888,
7777777,
6666666,
7777777,
8888888]
```

How can I check if first and last elements are the same and second and the one before last are the same? That is, could someone please explain how to check if an array is symmetric?

Additionally, how can I check if all numbers in the element are the same (e.g. "888888" is valid, "888886 is not)?

Comment: Well the really quick way would be to check `if ($array === array_reverse($array))` but if this is homework then I suspect that might not be the point...

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if `array[i] == array[size-i]` for all floor(size/2) elements.

Since you're using PHP, you might want to use `===` comparison instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to give you the exact code to complete your homework.

So, I think, first, you want to remove all elements that aren't a single character.

Cycle through the elements, and on each element, grab the first character. Then, cycle through the letters and check if they all equal that letter. If they don't, remove that element

---

Then, what you should try to do is reverse the array and check if the elements in the two arrays are equal. As in, the first element in the regular array equals the first element in the reversed array. That means that it's a symmetrical element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with array count: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

And you need to iterate in each string in the array, and in each character in the string to perform the numbers check.